# How to avoid opening IE on every loop?

Tags: html, excel, vba

After the great help I got here over the past days, I managed to finish my code for downloading xlsm files by selecting a range in excel and looping through the range.
Now I used the IE method, which opens a new IE instance for every entry. How can I avoid that ? I have over 50 entries in my range.

Is there a way to not open IE but still scrape the online data I need for the objID ?

```
Sub DownloadUpdate_Reviews()

Dim i As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim versch As String
Dim ordner As String
Dim dlURL As String
Dim enumm As String
Dim objID As String
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim ifrm As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim ifrm2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HttpReq As Object


'Select range
On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox( _
      Title:="Select Range", _
      prompt:="Select cell range with the E-numbers to download", _
      Type:=8)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  'Limit of allowed number of blank cells
  If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Rng) > 10 Then
  MsgBox "Too many blank cells in range.Limit is set to 10. Please dont select a whole column as range"
GoTo Toomanyblanks
End If

'Saving location
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Select where to save"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath


If .Show = -1 Then
ordner = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

'Skip blank cells in range
For Each i In Rng
If i = "" Then
GoTo Blank_i
End If

versch = i.Offset(0, -1)


'Get the objID
enumm = i
'Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://plm.corp.int:10090/enovia/common/emxFullSearch.jsp?pageConfig=tvc:pageconfig//tvc/search/AutonomySearch.xml&tvcTable=true&showInitialResults=true&cancelLabel=Close&minRequiredChars=3&genericDelete=true&selection=multiple&txtTextSearch=" & [i] & "&targetLocation=popup"

While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend


'choosing the right frame
Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).document
'Debug.Print HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).Name

'getting the specific object ID
objID = ifrm.getElementsByName("emxTableRowId")(0).Value
'Debug.Print objID



'start download
dlURL = "https://plm.corp.int:10090/enovia/tvc-action/downloadMultipleFiles?objectId=" & [objID] & ".xlsm"

Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
HttpReq.Open "GET", dlURL, False
HttpReq.send

dlURL = HttpReq.responseBody
If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile [ordner] & "\" & [i] & "_" & [versch] & ".xlsm", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite"
    oStrm.Close
End If


Blank_i:
Next

'quit InternetExplorer
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

Toomanyblanks:
End Sub
```

Error occurs in the following line: Member not found

```
Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).document
```

but it works if i manually navigate the code with F8. i guess, cause it has more execution time ?!

Comment: Just open the IE `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` outside your loop and use only `ie.navigate` (and the other interaction with IE) inside the loop. I mean you can re-use the same IE for all navigations and close the IE outside the loop when you are finised with your loop. That's all the magic. Where is your issue?

Comment: my issue is, that when i get to 
Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).document
it says the object wasnt found. probably because IE is too slow.

Comment: Did you only put this line `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium` outside the loop? The rest keep inside the loop.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes only that outside. But the thing is, i have to actually create a new instance for every loop, because my code accesses the html iframe to get some data. so if i put it outside. it doesnt work

Comment: These iframes are no reason not to re-use the same IE. That should work. • Please show the code that you tried and tell which error you get and in which line.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ see my edited code

Comment: Try using of `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` just before the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @FaneDuru a general wait of 1 second will slow it down 1 second **definitly**. Better to do it dynamically and let it proceed if it is faster, and put a time limit of eg 5 seconds. See my answer below.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Agreed. I just wanted to test if the delay is the problem. Then looping til the object is not Nothing will be the best... Edited: I say (now) your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that can be if there is some javascript involved and that isn't ready yet, and needs some more time. A workaround for that can be to try

```
Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).document
```

until it works (and have a maximum time limit for like 5 seconds, so you don't get stuck in an endless loop).

```
Dim TmrStart As Single
TmrStart = Timer 'initialize timer

Set ifrm = Nothing 'absolutely necessary otherwise the old frame could stay referenced.

Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).document
    On Error Goto 0

Loop While TmrStart + 5 > Timer AND ifrm Is Nothing

If ifrm Is Nothing Then
    Msgbox "The iframe was not found within 5 seconds. It finally failed."
End If
```

So this will try to find the iframe until it is found but for maximum 5 seconds. If it finds it earlier then it proceeds.

Comment: @DimitriosTop of course where your `Set ifrm = HTMLDoc.frames(0).frames(1).frames(0).document` is now. It replaces this line in your code.

Comment: Wow. Works like charme. Thanks! unfortunaterly it seems to cause a new error now, which i didnt get before while looping manually with F8. I get permission denied on some entries when i reach the line 
 objID = ifrm.getElementsByName("emxTableRowId")(0).Value

Comment: @DimitriosTop omg, sorry I forgot a `Set ifrm = Nothing` see my edit. This is absolutely necessary or you get wrong results. Please try again.

Comment: Solved the permission problem ! Now the code works but it occasionally still gives me the Member not found error after being in the loop for a while. still a time issue maybe?

Comment: Increase the time `TmrStart + 5` to a `+10` seconds or something if you think it is still a timing problem. You just should have a timelimit not to end up in a non-responding Excel because of a infinite loop. Actually the `+5` here is the maximum time that can be used. If it finds it earlier it will proceed earlier (it will only use the amount of time it needs but maximum `+5` seconds).

Comment: i dont know why...but setting ie.visible = False , solved the problem. THANK you for all your help :) any idea why that might have helped?

Comment: well if IE is not visible it doesn't need to calculate all the stuff that is needed to display it. So it is faster. No graphics rendering of the document needed.